# Why is my Makefile variable not assigned a default value here?

Tags: linux, makefile, overriding

Whenever I mention any version along with the execution command of this makefile that version should be stored in the variable VERSION, if no version is mentioned the default value should be taken.

This is my Makefile

```
export BUILDVERSION=$1
$(info    BUILDVERSION is "$(BUILDVERSION)")
ifneq ($(BUILDVERSION),undefined)
    override VERSION := $(BUILDVERSION)
else
    VERSION=VABCD.00.00A001
endif
$(info    VERSION is $(VERSION))
```

CASE 1: I'm getting this output when I include argument for execution

```
BUILDVERSION is "VABCD.00.00A001"
VERSION is "VABCD.00.00A001"
```

CASE 2: I'm getting this output when I do not include argument for execution

```
BUILDVERSION is ""
VERSION is ""
```

But, the expected output is

```
BUILDVERSION is ""
VERSION is "VABCD.00.00A001"
```

Since, if an argument is not given else case should run.
In my code else case is not taken for execution.

Could anyone please help me find what's wrong with my code!

Answer (score 1):

Lose `$1`, that is not how positional arguments such as `$1` are used in makefiles. `undefined` and `override` are also wrong as somebody else already answered.

Your makefile should be:

```
ifneq ($(BUILDVERSION),)
    VERSION := $(BUILDVERSION)
else
    VERSION=VABCD.00.00A001
endif
$(info    VERSION is $(VERSION))
```

You cannot call Make like this

`make VABCD.00.00A001`

you must call it like this

`make BUILDVERSION=VABCD.00.00A001`

You can also call it like this, maybe that will be OK with your requirements:

`BUILDVERSION=VABCD.00.00A001 make`

If you want to use an argument like `VABCD.00.00A001`, and not `BUILDVERSION=VABCD.00.00A001` then you cannot use Make, you should just write a shell script.  Your script can be a "wrapper" around Make - manipulate the argument to the way Make expects it and then call Make.

Answer (score 0):

Variable assignments on the command line normally override assignments in the makefile, so unless I am misunderstanding what you want to do, you could simply say

```
VERSION=VABCD.00.00A002
```

in the makefile, and then run make with

```
make VERSION=0.9beta1
```

to override the version number.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not allowed to run the make file in the format you said, version should be given as argument !

Comment: I'm not sure that's even possible. Command-line arguments are normally taken to be targets, and I don't think there's a general way of accessing those as makefile variables (though this proabably depends on which version of make you are using). Of course, it might be possible to cook up some horrible pattern rule that matches version numbers...

Comment: I have made the change , Thanks @Ture .But Again the code is not working well, I've updated the question, please look into the issue, Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

`ifneq ($(BUILDVERSION),undefined)` means "if the value of `BUILDVERSION` equals `'undefined'` string".

I guess the intent was `ifneq ($(origin BUILDVERSION),undefined)` (see [origin](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Origin-Function.html) function).

Note that an empty value IS a value, so you may want `ifneq ($(BUILDVERSION),)` sometimes.

No need for [override](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Override-Directive.html) directive here.